# Identify this plant, please

Tags: identification, houseplants

My neighbour showed it to me this morning, and she has no clue what this plant is. Her kid got this from school. I also have no idea what plant this is.

[image]
[image]

EDIT: Found this bigger version in a lawn. Probably this might help in the identification.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure what it is, but that looks like a tent caterpillar of some sort dangling off the leaf to the left in  the centre of the second picture...

Comment: @Bamboo But what about the plant? :)

Comment: No idea, might become more obvious over time

Comment: If that plant makes it.  She has obviously used garden soil in this pot.  Very bad thing to do.  Tell her to go get potting soil in a bag, not top soil, sterilized potting soil.  No rocks or gravel at the bottom just a drain hole.  Can't tell what it is, sure looks familiar but regardless, if she wants to keep this guy alive in a pot she's gonna have to repot in potting soil.  Obviously she could go to her kid's teacher and ask!  Also, only leave 1" of space from the top of the soil to the rim of the pot.  What is this teacher trying to teach?  They usually use beans of some sort...

Comment: @stormy Again you are correct. But there's no point in telling her. Adults these days just don't wanna hear anything correct. They like to live in a world full of false information and myths. I just hope the plant makes it.

Comment: @stormy And I got this new soil thinking it to be good soil with good drainage and nutrients, but it turned out to be this same garden soil. The tiny plant is already half eaten by rats, so it must be flowering plant or something the rats favour?

Comment: Rats will eat some foliage but mostly the fruit.  They know where the calories and nutrients are kept, grins!

Comment: @stormy  But they continue to eat my other devil's Ivy plant. I heard it is toxic to the rats, but they continue to eat it. Are they immune?

Comment: @4-K any progress?

Comment: @J.Musser Sadly, rats ate the plant :(

Comment: @J.Musser More pics added. Do you know what this plant is?